# How to convert a string-object to an real object

Tags: jquery, json, string, hash

Perhabs this questions should be named: *How to animate jQuery-objects through hash*.

Howsoever... How can I convert a string into an object? I've tried `JSON.parse` and `$.parseJSON` but get the following error-message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t`.

What I try to accomplish: I want to animate jQuery objects through a hash.

Here's my current state (Maybe there's a better way? Then tell it to me!):

```
var params = (location.hash || '#').substr(1).split('|');
$.map(params, function (e) {
    var parts = e.split('=');
    $(parts[0]).animate(parts[1]);
    console.log(typeof parts[1]); // 2 `string`
});
```

Use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/b2rru/0/show/) and attach these hash to the url:

`##foo={top:100,left:100}|#bar={top:100,right:100}`

(Sorry markdown doesn't allow me to append this kind of hash directly to the link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON isn't valid. (Paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ and see for yourself.)

JSON is stricter than JavaScript syntax and requires quoted object keys:

```
##foo={"top":100,"left":100}|#bar={"top":100,"right":100}
```

If you put quotes around `top`, `left`, and `right`, then you can just use `JSON.parse` or `$.parseJSON` on the JSON strings directly.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a bit more strict than JavaScript. The parameters would have to look like this for JSON evaluation:

```
{"top":100,"right":100}
```

If you don't want that, you must resort to good ol' `eval()`:

```
var params = eval('(' + parts + ')');
```

However, since you then allow execution of arbitrary JS via the URL, that might not be the way you're looking for.